# perl cyclic reference. Is this what is happening

Tags: perl, memory-management, memory-leaks, circular-reference, perl-data-structures

I am trying to write a daemon with perl. Now this daemon has the following code

```
sub b {
    my $data;
    if (some condition) {
         $data->{"endsmeet"} = 1;
    } else {
        $data->{"endsmeet"} = 2;
    }

    my $newData = a($data);
}

sub a {
    my ($data) = @_;
    my %a = ();
    my $newData = {
      endsmeet => undef,
    };
    $a{"boo"} = $data->{"endsmeet"};
    $newData->{"endsmeet"} = \%a;
    return $newData;
}
```

My question is from the above, does the reference for %a go away and does it get cleaned up when b goes out of scope?

Comment: OT: That should be `my %a = ();` which is just a silyl way of writing `my %a;`. Always use `use strict; use warnings;`

Comment: There you go. But, does it make sense on what I am saying? I am worried that I may be leaking memory here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`b` returns the value of `$newdata`, which is a reference to an anon hash, which holds a reference to `%a`, which holds a scalar in the element with key `boo`.

If the value returned by `b` not stored, nothing will be referencing the value of `$newdata`, so it will get freed, so nothing will be referencing the anon hash, so it will get freed, so nothing will reference the scalar in the element with key `boo`, so it will get freed.

No cycles. No leak.